# HTML - How to center an element when its parent element sets "display: table"?

Tags: html, css

I use a table view to align my form. At the same time, I hope that the submission button is in the middle of the form, but the browser always seems to put it in the middle of the table cell.

[image: The result of my code]

```css
form {
  display: table;
}
form > div {
  display: table-row;
}
form > div > label {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
form > input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="user-name">
    <label for="user-name">User Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="user-name" id="user-name" />
  </div>
  <div class="password">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: _"but the browser always seems to put it in the middle of the table cell."_ - what "cell"? This is a direct child of your `display: table` element, so there should be a table _row_ now first of all. And the input is not a "cell" either, you gave it `display: block`. Why are you using table display types for this in the first place? flexbox and grid exist.

Comment: I tried changing the width of the submit button to make it as wide as the `form`, but it never exceeds the width of the `label` above, as if there is a table cell restricting it.
When I unset `display: table-cell` for the `label`, the submit button is successfully centered.
I don't understand, why styles set for other elements would unexpectedly affect unrelated elements.@CBroe

Comment: The table layout rules means that there are anonymous table-row and table-cell objects around your submit button. So the submit button is constrained to the first column of the table and centered within that. Table is the wrong layout model for this. Grid is the correct one - ideally one would use subgrid for the divs but I don't think that browser implementations are quite there yet - but the layout can be achieved using Grid by setting the divs to `display:contents`. If you don't want to go down that route, @zangab's answer gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Flex instead of Table! I believe flex may be a more viable option for what you are trying to achieve because it offers more *flexibility* as far as orienting & aligning content.

```css
form {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.user-name,
.password {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

form > div > label {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

form > input[type='submit'] {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="user-name">
    <label for="user-name">User Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="user-name" id="user-name" />
  </div>
  <div class="password">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You need to ensure that the `input` to the right of the `label` is the same width, otherwise the `label` will not be aligned. For example, when I add `<input type="radio">`, it will not be as wide as `<input type="text">`. Probably the best way is to use `grid`.

Answer (score 1):

This would be `display: table` version. Your `margin` does not work in a table. Additionally, there's no `colspan` available. Therefore you have to `position: absolute` a child and span it the whole width (or in your case, center it with `left` and `transform`).

So either use a real `<table>` OR - as it's 2023 - use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or the newer [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

```css
form {
  display: table;
}
form > div {
  display: table-row;
}
form > div > label {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.submit-btn {
  position: relative;
}

form input[type="submit"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="user-name">
    <label for="user-name">User Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="user-name" id="user-name" />
  </div>
  <div class="password">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
  </div>
  <div class="submit-btn"><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" /></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.user-name,
.password {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.user-name input,
.password input {
    float: right;
}
.submitButton {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<form>
            <div class="user-name">
                <label for="user-name">User Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="user-name" id="user-name" />
            </div>
            <div class="password">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            </div>
            <div class="submitButton">
                <input type="submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

As the code above you can change your display style and add more form elements just like this and this will give the perfect look, hope this helps, comment if you need anything else.